# Light & effective firewall to block a program

Tags: windows-7, firewall

My laptop system is Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

I'm looking for a light firewall to only block some programs to access to net.

I've tried Comodo but it slows my laptop too much. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since I don't use a basic firewall, I cannot recommend one. Do your own research at http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-firewall-protection.htm#Basic-Firewalls which, BTW, is an excellent site for finding FreeWare which has been reviiewed & rated (does anyone know of a better?).

Comment: As a result i've started using Windows 10 firewall. It doesn't effect my computer's system and it's effective. Thank you for the help.